# CSV data(Not file, directly putting the data in code ) placement in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts, heatmap

Hi I want to know the right way to store this CSV data, I have stored it in var data but it throws error.

```
var data = Events,Apps,Status
    Business Requirement Description,App1,60
    Communication to Stake Holders,App1,50
    Development Started,App1,30
    Reviewed ,App1,10
    Ready for E2E Testing,App1,5
    Business Requirement Description,App2,80
    Communication to Stake Holders,App2,40
    Development Started,App2,20
    Reviewed ,App2,10
    Ready for E2E Testing,App2,0
    Business Requirement Description,App3,100
    Communication to Stake Holders,App3,60
    Development Started,App3,0
    Reviewed ,App3,30
    Ready for E2E Testing,App3,0
```

Here Im parsing the data using Highcharts functionalities to create a Heatmap:

```
function(data){
    var lines = data.split('\n');
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(','); 
    });

    // Defining X-Axis: 
    $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
        if(itemNo == 0){
            $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
                if (lineNo > 0)
                    options.xAxis.categories.push(item)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to store it as a string.

```
var data = `
    Events,Apps,Status
    Business Requirement Description,App1,60
    Communication to Stake Holders,App1,50
    Development Started,App1,30
    Reviewed ,App1,10
    Ready for E2E Testing,App1,5
    Business Requirement Description,App2,80
    Communication to Stake Holders,App2,40
    Development Started,App2,20
    Reviewed ,App2,10
    Ready for E2E Testing,App2,0
    Business Requirement Description,App3,100
    Communication to Stake Holders,App3,60
    Development Started,App3,0
    Reviewed ,App3,30
    Ready for E2E Testing,App3,0`
```

If your environment does not support back ticks (some older browsers don't support back ticks):

```
 var data = "Events,Apps,Status\nBusiness Requirement Description,App1,60\nCommunication to Stake Holders,App1,50\nDevelopment Started,App1,30\nReviewed ,App1,10\nReady for E2E Testing,App1,5\nBusiness Requirement Description,App2,80\nCommunication to Stake Holders,App2,40\nDevelopment Started,App2,20\nReviewed ,App2,10\nReady for E2E Testing,App2,0\nBusiness Requirement Description,App3,100\nCommunication to Stake Holders,App3,60\nDevelopment Started,App3,0\nReviewed ,App3,30\nReady for E2E Testing,App3,0"
```

Notes:

You can also use an online [CSV to JSON converter](https://www.csvjson.com/csv2json) if you are hardcoding this data into the file. You can use the JSON object directly as a JS object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your CSV string in quotes:

```
var data = "Events,Apps,Status
Business Requirement Description,App1,60
Communication to Stake Holders,App1,50
Development Started,App1,30
Reviewed ,App1,10
Ready for E2E Testing,App1,5
Business Requirement Description,App2,80
Communication to Stake Holders,App2,40
Development Started,App2,20
Reviewed ,App2,10
Ready for E2E Testing,App2,0
Business Requirement Description,App3,100
Communication to Stake Holders,App3,60
Development Started,App3,0
Reviewed ,App3,30
Ready for E2E Testing,App3,0"
```